# Select from select with a count

Tags: mysql, count

Ok i believe I've done something similar before, but don't really remember how I did it.

Searching around gives me similar answer's but not solving my issue.

Ex1, This query is fine:

```
SELECT col1, count(*) as col3
FROM db.table
WHERE col2 = 0 group by col1
```

Ex2, But I need all where col3 is bigger than 1, so I tried:

```
Select *
FROM
(SELECT col1, count(*) as col3
FROM db.table 
WHERE col2 = 0 group by col1)
WHERE col3 > 1;
# Not working
```

Ex3, I dont know why but this seems to be working:

```
SELECT col1, count(*) as col3
FROM db.table
WHERE col2 = 0
GROUP BY col1
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Why the downvote, people seems to just be downvoting question for no reason, notice that I also answered my own question while I was writing it so I thought, hey maybe it could help somebody else.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I just answered my own question when I read the error message from Mysql.

```
Select *
FROM
(SELECT col1, count(*) as col3
FROM db.table 
WHERE col2 = 0 group by col1) temp
WHERE col3 > 1;
```

I was missing the alias.